# Update the view after web request fires?

Tags: angular

Using Angular 5, I am passing a selected object property, `ID` into a function, `getqr()` in another component that fires a web request. Even though the request and its results are being logged properly, the results are not being displayed in the view which is keeping its original state. How can I have the component showing the results reflect the selection?

HTML for selection:

```
<table>
  <tr>
    <th></th>
    <th>Document Group</th>
    <th>Title</th>
    <th>Description</th>
  </tr>

  <tr *ngFor="let doc of docs">
    <td><input type="checkbox" [(ngModel)]="doc.selected" (change)="select(doc.ID, doc.selected)"></td>
    <td>{{doc.DocumentGroup}}</td>
    <td>{{doc.Title}}</td>
    <td>{{doc.Description}}</td>
  </tr>
</table>

<app-print></app-print>
```

TS for selection:

```
  select(ID, selected){
    if (selected == true) {
      this.print.selecteditems.push(ID);
    }
    else {
      var index = this.print.selecteditems.indexOf(ID);
      this.print.selecteditems.splice(index, 1);
    }
    this.print.getqr(ID); //FIRES FUNCTION FROM PRINT COMPONENT
  }
```

HTML for 'Print' view that I want to refresh when `getqr()` fires:

```
<div *ngFor="let item of barcodeitems" id="pagebreak">
  <div class="qrcode">
    <qrcode [qrdata]="item.Title" [size]="256" [level]="'M'"></qrcode>
  </div>

  <div class="qrinfo">
    {{item.DocumentGroup}}<br>
    <b>{{item.Title}}</b><br>
    {{item.Description}}
  </div>
</div>
```

TS for Print component:

```
  getqr(ID) {
    let filterQuery = this.selecteditems.map(i => `ID eq '${i}'`).join(" or ");
    let url = `example.com/dev/_api/web/lists/getbytitle('Document Separator Barcodes')/items?$top=1000&$orderBy=ID&$filter=${filterQuery}`
    this.http.get(url).subscribe(data => {
      console.log("data.value", data['value']); //Results log here correctly
      this.barcodeitems = data['value'];
    });
  }
```

How do I refresh the view of the Print component when `getqr()` has completed?

Comment: `this.print.getqr(ID);` here, what  is `this.print`, a service or component?

Comment: That is triggering the `getqr()` function from the Print component.

Comment: Oh, you are getting a reference to print component from template. This is what `this.print` refers to? Try my answer and let me know if you have  difficulties.

Comment: Yes. After the `select` function is completed in the first component, it fires `getqr` from the Print component which does a web request for the selected items.

Answer (score 1):

Inside the component where you want to trigger update (trigger or mark Angular change detection manually), you can use `ChangeDetectorRef.markForCheck()` or `ChangeDetectorRef.detectChanges()`.

e.g.

```
import { Component,  ... , ChangeDetectorRef } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
    ...
})
export class PrintComponent implements OnInit {
    constructor(private cdr: ChangeDetectorRef, // Inject ChangeDetectorRef                  
                ...) {
    }

    getqr(ID)
    {
        let filterQuery = this.selecteditems.map(i => `ID eq '${i}'`).join(" or ");
        let url = `https://portal.oldnational.com/corporate/portalsupport/_api/web/lists/getbytitle('Document Separator Barcodes')/items?$top=1000&$orderBy=ID&$filter=${filterQuery}`
        this.http.get(url).subscribe(data => {
            console.log("data.value", data['value']); //Results log here correctly
            this.barcodeitems = data['value'];

            // After assignment, trigger change detection
            this.cdr.detectChanges();
        });
    }
}
```

**Note** prefer `ChangeDetectorRef.markForCheck()` if it works for you. [Reference](https://angular.io/api/core/ChangeDetectorRef).

Comment: Right now, this breaks the app where I can't see either view.

Comment: `NullInjectorError: No provider for ChangeDetectorRef!`. I am trying to add it to providers in app.module.ts but I am getting the error: ` Argument of type '{ declarations: (typeof AppComponent | typeof PrintComponent)[]; imports: (typeof BrowserModule |...' is not assignable to parameter of type 'NgModule'. Types of property 'providers' are incompatible. Type '(typeof PrintComponent | typeof ChangeDetectorRef)[]' is not assignable to type 'Provider[]'. Type 'typeof PrintComponent | typeof ChangeDetectorRef' is not assignable to type 'Provider'.`

Comment: Have you injected it in print component's constructor (like in my example)?

Comment: Yes, with: `constructor(public http: HttpClient, private cdr: ChangeDetectorRef){}`

Comment: It should work just by importing and injecting it in the component, because it is provided by **@angular/core** module.

Comment: I was able to add `ChangeDetectorRef` to the selection component without any issues. However, the issues still remain on the Print component (where it's actually needed).

Comment: Do you want to figure it out on screen sharing?

Comment: As much as I'd like to, this is a company project and I would not be able to. I appreciate all of your help and will update the post if I find a solution.

Comment: I see. Have  you injected it in PrintComponent as well?

Comment: Yes, my imports are `import { Component, OnInit, ChangeDetectorRef } from '@angular/core';`. I'm still getting the provider errors even though I am unable to add `ChangeDetectorRef` as a provider.

Comment: `ChangeDetectorRef` can't be provided. It can only be imported and injected. Are you injecting it in print component's constructor like `constructor(private cdr: ChangeDetectorRef, ... ` ?

Comment: In the print component I have the constructor as: `constructor(public http: HttpClient, private cdr: ChangeDetectorRef){}` and the function `getqr()` as `getqr() {.....this.cdr.detectChanges()}`. This gives me an error of `StaticInjectorError(AppModule)[PrintComponent -> ChangeDetectorRef]: 
  StaticInjectorError(Platform: core)[PrintComponent -> ChangeDetectorRef]: 
    NullInjectorError: No provider for ChangeDetectorRef!`

Comment: Hmm, don't know why it is doing it. I use it almost in every Angular component.
Anyway, try this, remove cdr. In `getqr` inside `subscribe`, wrap the assignment in `setTimeout`. `setTimeout` also triggers Angular's change detection.

`setTimeout(() => {
  this.barcodeitems = data['value'];
});`

Comment: No errors, but the view is not being updated after a selection.